# how to display converted byte array as image in datagrid

Tags: c#, sql, datagrid, arrays

I want to be able to show images in my datagrid. I am pulling all info from a sql database. The images are in the database as byte arrays. I am pretty sure I have figured out the part of how to convert from byte arrays back to the image, now I am trying to figure out how to display the image in the grid after it has been converted. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Edit Columns > Column Type > Select DataGridViewImageColumn