# Converting and displaying a byte array as an image in a datagrid

Tags: c#, sql, datagrid, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to display converted byte array as image in datagrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048612/how-to-display-converted-byte-array-as-image-in-datagrid)

I have inserted images into a sql database. I want to display these images in a datagrid. Currently in my datagrid, I just have a image column and each cell in that column just says Byte[]Array. So i need to convert these byte arrays back to an image and then display these images in the datagrid. I am drawing a blank as to how to do this. any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I'm not seeing any code, perhaps you forgot to post what you've tried so far.

Comment: can i assume this is webforms? if so, you'll have to write to the response. you'll probably end up having to create your own file handler (which is pretty simple).

Comment: you should answer the comments

Comment: Sorry, I normally do...I got really busy at work after posting this...
@Justin - no, I am not using webforms.

@Fosco - I really dont have any code to show as of yet...i was looking for something to get me jump started.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to inherit from DataGridViewCell and  create you own that can convert the byte array to a Bitmap and draw it on herself.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.aspx

Then with this sample here you'll learn how to use it on your datagrid.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.aspx

Comment: Thanks for these links, I will look at them today and try to come up with something.